# exec php takes long time

Tags: php, ubuntu, websocket, exec, daemon

I am executing one daemon file through php file like:

```
echo exec("php -q /var/www/project/server.php");
```

but it takes so long time, and also noticed that its creating two process for the same like:

```
5558 ?        S      0:00 sh -c php -q /var/www/project/server.php

5559 ?        S      0:00 php -q /var/www/project/server.php
```

So please help me that why its creating two processes ?

**And how to speedup execution ?**

I am using php 5.5 , ubuntu

**Updated**

I have use Ratchet for websocket 
Here is the code of server.php

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new WsServer(
        new DraftAuction()
    )
    , 8181
);

$server->run();  // If I comment this line getting response faster but I cant do that, this line keeps process in continues running mode.
```

Comment: Your output suggests PHP took 0 seconds of CPU time to execute. Perhaps some code in `server.php` hangs up or blocks waiting for system events. Try to locate the line which blocks execution and post the code here.

Comment: PHP executes the command passed to `exec()`, `system()`, `shell_exec()`, `popen()` or `proc_open()` in a shell. That's why you see two processes. The other part of your question: *"Why does it take so long"* obviously can't answered since your question is missing essential information.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev & hek2mgl : Thanks for your answer, Question updated, please help me out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process 5558 is your shell.  It is there to spawn the child process, 5559, which is the actual process running the PHP script, your WebSocket server.  Process 5558 will continue to wait until the child process finishes its execution.  (Specifically, it's waiting for the child process to be detached from the terminal, either through terminating normally (which includes becoming a daemon on its own), or through becoming a background process and detaching its outputs.)

Your first PHP script, which has the `exec()` statement, is waiting for the process that *it* created to finish execution before it returns any values.  Since 5558 will not return until 5559 returns, your first PHP script will also not return.

Your options are:

1. Turn your server.php script into a daemon.
2. Detach from the terminal before the script even starts.

In option one, fork, kill parent, close STDOUT and STDERR, fork again, kill parent.  No, I won't go into more detail, because to do it justice really requires a full chapter on Posix processes in a nice thick reference book.

In option two, change your `exec()` statement as follows:

```
exec("php -q /var/www/project/server.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

This redirects your output to `/dev/null` (nowhere), and puts the process into a background state.  There is no point to the `echo` because there's nothing for it to print out.

Your shell will then be able to exit (there's nothing for it to wait for), and your original script can then complete successfully, with a new WebSocket server running headless.

And, I'd like to point out real quick: This really isn't a WebSocket question, nor a programming question.  It's a Unix/Linux question, and the root of the issue is more thoroughly answered over on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely

Answer (score 1):

I had some audio processing to be done and ran in to the same problem.

Use the back ticks `` and pass the command. Runs the same as when executed from the shell.

Example:

```
$command = "rubberband --tempo "  . $factor . " " . $input . " " . $output;
`$command`;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, is `$server->run();` even supposed to return? It looks like it listens on port 8181, waiting for clients to connect, and it will probably never exit by itself.

Comment: Yeah thats right, that will stay in running mode, so how to handle this situation, please help me

Comment: Well, if you don't need it running, why do you start it in the first place? What exactly do you expect from running the server?